# How should I use my own OAuth2 service with a javascript web app without looking like a 3rd party app?

Tags: javascript, oauth

I've been debating this with my colleagues but we have no clear solution. OAuth gurus, your wisdom is needed please!

**Context:**

My company "CompanyX" is exposing a set of REST APIs which are protected behind an own OAuth2 service. I have full control over the OAuth implementation.

3rd party developers use the API and OAuth to develop apps.

My company plans to develop a client-side ONLY web application for desktop and mobile browsers. Users of this app log into their account with a username/password. In the spirit of "eating our own dog food", the new web app will use the existing REST APIs and OAuth service.

Instinctively, I would have my app use the OAuth2 password grant-type.

**Problem Statement:**

Picture this: as a user, you press the Login button on the AppX (my app) developed by CompanyX (my company). It redirects you to a box that reads:

> "AppX by CompanyX" wants to access your CompanyX data, do you allow
>   it?

This doesn't look right: CompanyX shouldn't have to ask the user's permission to access the data it itself manages, right? How should OAuth be used here, which OAuth grant type should be used that doesn't compromise the app secret (this is a client-only "insecure" web app) ?

Thanks
Remi